# java parseint - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am writing a sudoku program in netbeans and heres the code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    int[][] sudoku = new int [4][4];


    sudoku[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
    sudoku[1][0] = Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
    sudoku[2][0] = Integer.parseInt(t5.getText());
    sudoku[3][0] = Integer.parseInt(t6.getText());
    sudoku[0][1] = Integer.parseInt(t3.getText());
    sudoku[1][1] = Integer.parseInt(t4.getText());
    sudoku[2][1] = Integer.parseInt(t7.getText());
    sudoku[3][1] = Integer.parseInt(t8.getText());
    sudoku[0][2] = Integer.parseInt(t9.getText());
    sudoku[1][2] = Integer.parseInt(t10.getText());
    sudoku[2][2] = Integer.parseInt(t13.getText());
    sudoku[3][2] = Integer.parseInt(t14.getText());
    sudoku[0][3] = Integer.parseInt(t11.getText());
    sudoku[1][3] = Integer.parseInt(t12.getText());
    sudoku[2][3] = Integer.parseInt(t15.getText());
    sudoku[3][3] = Integer.parseInt(t16.getText());

    if (sudoku[1][1] == sudoku[2][1])
    { 
        jLabel1.setText("true");
    }

}
```

and it gives this error everytime:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For       input string: ""

it will be great if you guys can figure out what is wrong and maybe write try catch exception(because i don't know how to write it) thank you

Comment: what number do you think that "" should be converted to?

Comment: This doesn't require a `try...catch`. Rather you need some error checking to correctly handle a blank text field. Also, you clearly know how to use arrays. I suggest you put this knowledge to use with your text fields rather than using variable names that only differ by a numerical suffix. In fact a 2D array of text fields would allow you to reduce your code to three lines of code using some for loops.

Comment: This is an obvious, and very very bad practice.. how do you determine any of your "tn.getText()" method will not return a "null" or "". which causes a NPE...where is the exception handling??

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva Ummm...there is no NPE here. And exception handling shouldn't be necessary if the OP adds appropriate if statements.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Oh yes! my mistake of reading, Thanks. yes it surely returns NFE when getText() is "" and could be avoided conditionally as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that in your code "" should be synonymous with "0" then create a small method

```
int getNumber (String str) {

   if (str.equals ("")) {
        return 0;
   } 

   return Integer.parseInt (str);
}
```

this can then be called from you code

```
sudoku[0][0] = getNumber(t1.getText());
```

Comment: In addition to this solution, I advice to use `trim()` to avoid any additional spaces/tabs. Alternatively, you can use try/catch to return "0" in case of any error.